# Are these temperatures normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, cpu, temperature

I have a 13-inch, Mid 2012 Macbook Pro that constantly overheats. Normally, the only app I will be using will be Google Chrome and I will still experience these temperatures. But occasionally I use Adobe Photoshop and Lightroom and my Mac gets even hotter. Here are the temperatures according to iStat.

[image]
[image]

Should I be worried? Should I get a new fan?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The processors are designed to run at 100 C which is within the margin of measuring error for the thermocouples in my experience.

The blower speed looks good and you might get a little extra work done if you can put it in a cooler room or get more airflow overall under the body of external case and lower the top case / battery temps a bit.

- [MacBook Pro Early 2015 13" temperature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261384/macbook-pro-early-2015-13-temperature)
- [Is it normal for a 15 inch rMBP to get extremely hot during use?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94374/is-it-normal-for-a-15-inch-rmbp-to-get-extremely-hot-during-use)

The CPU and other temps will still be high throttle work to keep things at max temp and even in a 50 F degree room you would expect everything but the palm rest and battery to be warm for CPU intensive workloads.

- [Fan Speed and Temperature on MBP Retina 13 2013](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94013/fan-speed-and-temperature-on-mbp-retina-13-2013)

I might have someone that knows how to use delicate screwdrivers to check for lint or dust in the case, but absent other signs you have what looks to be normal sensor readings.